# Java exec linux command

Tags: linux, process, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec)

Hello i wrote simple java function using exec command. This function check that font exist in system (linux). First i wrote simple bash command : `identify -list font | grep  -i 'Font: Times-Bold' -w` and its work perfectly so i create simple program:

```
public abstract class SystemReader{

    public static final void checkFontExist(String name){
            String command = "identify -list font | grep -i -w \'Font: "  + name + "\'";
            Process p  =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            String lines = "";
            String resoults ="";
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while((line  buferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    resoult += line + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + resoult);
            bufferreader.close();
    }
```

}

Its working but not i espect. This function return all fonts exist in my system . 
Its seems that command grep is not exec  ?

i try use another version of command exec() i create :

```
String command = {"identify -list font", "grep -i -w \'Font: " + fontName + "\'"}
```

but i have got error  :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify -list font ": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
```

Can you give me advice what is wrong ? thanks a lot

Comment: piping is provided by the shell so you'll need to pass the results from one command into the other manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String[] cmd = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "identify -list font | grep -i -w \'Font: "  + name + "\'"
};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Will pass the command through the shell. Which is what you need since the | (pipe) command is provided by the shell and not the Operating System.