# Execute a linux terminal command in java?

Tags: java, linux, sox

i'm trying to execute a SOX command from java, but unfortunately its returning an error everytime. Every other SOX commands are working perfectly though!!
Here is the code :

```
class Simple {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception {
        Process p;
        BufferedReader br;
        String co = "sox speech_16.wav -p pad 0 2.5 | sox - -m speech_16.wav speech_output.wav";
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(co);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("reurn code : "+returnCode);         
    }
}
```

When I'm executing the same sox command in terminal, its working fine. I really can't understand what the problem is!! Is it because of the '|' symbol??

Comment: Its returning 1. Actually it should return 0.

Comment: and what does a return code of 1 from sox mean (check the man page)?

Comment: @codebox means there is some error in its output or the 'output-file' has not been generated! According to the above command it should generate a file called "speech_output.wav".

Comment: @codebox The problem is not with the command! i think [I'm not sure] the problem is with the String when it get parsed!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that Runtime.exec() does not understand shell concepts such as "|". Instead try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh", "-c", co);
```

The problem is that exec runs a binary directly without invoking the shell. The "|" character is only recognized by the shell, not by sox. The "-c" tells the shell to run a single command, and passes the entire command as the single argument.

Comment: It's not the directory path - it's the pipe that's the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316/184998

Comment: But i really need to include '|' for working. Is there any way to include that?

Comment: yeah! it worked!! thanx @AdrianCox . It was because of the pipe symbole. Here is the code : String[] co = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "sox speech_16.wav -p pad 0 2.5 | sox - -m speech_16.wav speech_output.wav"
    };
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(co);

Comment: @epsalon can you elborate on `-c` argument, please?

Comment: I added more detail to the answer. Hope this clears stuff up.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely to be related to the environment in which the commands get executed, it could be any of the following:

- The `sox` executable cannot be found (put the full path in the command)
- The user does not have permission to run the `sox` command (check execute bit in file permissions)
- Some environment variable needed by `sox` is not initialised when you run the command from Java (check sox documentation)
- If `speech_16.wav` is an input file to `sox` then the file cannot be found (add full path of .wav file to command)
- If `sox` needs to create an output file then it does not have permission to do so, either due to directory permissions, of because there is an existing file with that name which cannot be overwritten, or due to lack of space on the file-system.

Comment: It worked finally. It was because of the pipe symbol in the command. Thanks for your help btw :)