# Execute linux terminal commands in Java which involves writing to logfile, but doesn't have permission?

Tags: java, linux, shell

Here is the code:

```
String cmd = "/usr/local/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/postgresql/data >logfile 2>&1 &";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

It doesn't work. The command is supposed to start the postgres server, but I checked that the server didn't start which means the command wasn't executed. But it worked if the command is like this: `/usr/local/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/postgresql/data` which just start the server but no need to write to logfile.

So I guess the characters in the command maybe a problem. And I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364315/execute-a-linux-terminal-command-in-java). It still didn't work though. Then I realized maybe it's the permission issue? I mean the java file doesn't have the permission to write to the logfile? But I don't know how to solve this one. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, we're able to get a handle to the console and error streams and then do with them what we please.

Instead of "> logfile ...", could you get a handle to the output streams from `p` and then write to your log file programmatically?

Same for the "&" at the end. Your `Process` API might have a method to put it in the background.

To rule out permissions, change "logfile" in your example above to something like "/tmp/mytemporarylogfile.txt" and see if that helps. (I doubt it will because I don't think it likes your shell constructs of ">", "2>&1", and "&" inside of Java. Imagine what this would do if you ran it on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [Process.getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29) to get the error stream, and with this you can its content in a file. Easier, it seems the class ProcessBuilder has a method to redirect the output to a file [ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.io.File%29)

However, I would't think there is a way to execute the command in background. That's make sense in a shell, but in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to a file using the '>' operator is a function of the shell, not something inherent to the OS.  You either need to spawn a shell that then runs the process, or read the output of the process and write it to the log file from Java.