# Executing complex command with commons-exec

Tags: java, command-line, imagemagick

I have been strugling to get a command executed through a simple Java application. 
The command I need to execute is found at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text (above title "Watermarking with Images), and is the following:

```
convert -size 140x80 xc:none -fill grey -gravity NorthWest -draw "text 10,10 'Copyright'" -gravity SouthEast -draw "text 5,15 'Copyright'" miff:- | composite -tile - /Users/latu/Pictures/desert.jpg  /Users/latu/Pictures/desertCP.jpg
```

(I have tested the command by entering it directly into terminal and it works)

I cannot get the command created properly. Using my code the following command is constructed:

```
convert -size 140x80 xc:none -fill grey -gravity NorthWest -draw "text 10,10 'Copyright" -gravity SouthEast -draw "text 5,15 'Copyright" miff:- | composite -title - /Users/latu/Pictures/desert.jpg /Users/latu/Pictures/desertCP.jpg
```

Also, a number of errors are returned which are relevant to image magick:

```
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text 10,10 'Copyright' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3178.
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text 5,15 'Copyright' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3178.
convert: unable to open image `- |': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert: unable to open image `composite': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert: unable to open image `composite': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `composite' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
convert: unrecognized option `-title' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2984.
```

If anyone knows what I need to change in my code to construct the correct command, or knows a better approach please let me know.

> The parts of the code that definetly cause trouble are ' ' around
>   Copyright which are not printed in the generated command, and the pipe
>   command at `.addArgument("miff:- | ",false);`

Here is the code im using:

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;
import java.io.IOException;

class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        applyWatermark(null,null);
    }

    public static void applyWatermark(String imagePaath,String watermark){
        String imagePath = "/Users/latu/Pictures/desert.jpg";
        String imagePath2 = "/Users/latu/Pictures/desertCP.jpg";

        CommandLine convert_cmd = new CommandLine("convert");
        convert_cmd.addArgument("-size")
                .addArgument("140x80")
                .addArgument("xc:none")
                .addArgument("-fill")
                .addArgument("grey")
                .addArgument("-gravity")
                .addArgument("NorthWest")
                .addArgument("-draw")
                .addArgument( "text 10,10 'Copyright'")
                .addArgument("-gravity")
                .addArgument("SouthEast")
                .addArgument("-draw")
                .addArgument("text 5,15 'Copyright'")
                .addArgument("miff:- |",false);
//      CommandLine wm_cmd = new CommandLine("composite");
        convert_cmd.addArgument("composite")
                .addArgument("-title")
                .addArgument("- "+imagePath,false)
                .addArgument(imagePath2);


        System.out.println(convert_cmd.toString());

        executeCommand(convert_cmd);
//      executeCommand(wm_cmd);

        /*
         http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text
         correct command: convert -size 140x80 xc:none -fill grey -gravity NorthWest -draw "text 10,10 'Copyright'" -gravity SouthEast -draw "text 5,15 'Copyright'" miff:- | composite -tile - /Users/latu/Pictures/desert.jpg  /Users/latu/Pictures/desertCP.jpg
         */
    }
    private static  void executeCommand(CommandLine cmdLine){
        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();

        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60*1000);
        Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
        try
        {
            executor.execute(cmdLine, resultHandler);
        } catch (ExecuteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote here - `"text 10,10 'Copyright"`

Comment: Or here... `.addArgument( "text 10,10 'Copyright''")`

Comment: I didn't realise that was still in the code, was left after experimenting. Having "text 10,10 'Copyright'" prints a command without ' ' around Copyright for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the accepted answer on t[his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec) I have changed my code to the following which is working as expected:

```
    String [] cmd ={"-c","convert -size 140x80 xc:none -fill grey -gravity NorthWest -draw \"text 10,10 'Copyright'\" -gravity SouthEast -draw \"text 5,15 'Copyright'\" miff:- | composite -tile - /Users/latu/Pictures/desert.jpg  /Users/latu/Pictures/desertCP.jpg"};
    CommandLine convert_cmd = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
    convert_cmd.addArguments( cmd,false );
```