# NETSH produces no output

Tags: java, runtime.exec, netsh

I am trying to use following command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh -c interface dump > c:\\location1.txt");
```

But it produces no output.

I know we have to separate command and its arguments i tried but still failed.

I used following way.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh",new String[] "-c", "interface", "dump >", "c:\\location1.txt");
```

But still produces no output.

If anyone knows how to use all or some of the NETSH commands using runtime then it will be great helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process=pb.start();
BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

while(inStreamReader.readLine() != null){
    //do something with commandline output.
}
```

Comment: it throws exception here it is "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "netsh -c interface dump > C:\local.txt": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at com.kamani.proxyloader.ExecuteCommand.main(ExecuteCommand.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Should be like this `new ProcessBuilder("netsh.exe", "-c", "interface","dump");` No `> C:\local.txt` at all.

Comment: ya i done it but i got output in console because i written System.out.println() in loop so now i have to manually write in file.

Answer (score 1):

This is `netsh`on Windows ? Try to specifi full path to executable:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/full/path/netsh.exe",...
```

Comment: it's still not working.All other command works but i don't know why above command is not working.

Comment: You cannot redirect the output. The redirect `>` is part of a shell command. You may catch the `netsh`output as @A Paul said or start `cmd.exe` with a commandline. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec

Comment: ya you are right but i am still unable to understand can you tell me how can i resolve this issue?