# Running grep command on procinfo output

Tags: java, grep

I want to find idle percentage of processor but it is showing all procinfo output

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("procinfo | grep idle");
while((s=stdInput.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: It's a beautiful sunny day.

Comment: Do you understand what pipe `|` means, right?

Comment: Have a look here - [How to make pipes work with runtime exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ProcInfo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] command = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "procinfo | grep -oP '^idle.* \\K[0-9.]+%'" };
        try
        {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();

            InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[16];
            i.read(b, 0, b.length);
            System.out.println(new String(b));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Special Thanks to **Cyrus** for the command.