# grep command is not working with git blame files and git log for a revision

Tags: java, linux, git, runtime

I am trying to run below code:

```
public class StandOnLinux {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //String commandToBeExecuted = "git blame  '"+files[i]+"' | grep "+revision+" | awk '{print $7}'";
    //String commandToBeExecuted = "git --git-dir D:\\code_coverage\\.git blame src\\RunCodeCoverage.java | grep 'e4ecfbe'"; git blame --git-dir D:/code_coverage/.git src/RunCodeCoverage.java| grep 59e3fdc | gawk '{print $7}'
    String commandToBeExecuted = "git blame  StandOnLinux.java  --grep=\"e8a93e7d\"";
    String temp = "";
    File file = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin");
    System.out.println(commandToBeExecuted);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted);
    //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", commandToBeExecuted});
    //Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted, null, file);  
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));  

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
        p.getErrorStream()));
    while((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(temp);
    }
    while((temp = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(temp);
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives me results without grepping the output as mentioned in grep.

Can anyone tell what is wrong i am doing in this code?

Running this code on Linux machine.

Comment: On which repo you are running command?

Comment: I have a local git repo, where i have code checked out,  "git --git-dir **/home/data/gitCode/.git** blame StandOnLinux.java ";//"git blame  StandOnLinux.java  | grep e8a93e7d"

Comment: Try any other command first to see if it works i.e. `git log` or something.

Comment: `--grep` flag does nothing for `git blame` command. check it with command line and it won't grep anything as well. W

Comment: @Foolish, i have tried run **git --git-dir **/home/data/gitCode/.git ** log --pretty=format:\"revision=\"%h\",%nauthor=\"%an\",%nmessage=\"%s\",%ndate=\"%cd\",\" --grep="message" ** and this is working properly and gives desired output. Issue is only when i use grep with blame, even this blame command mentioned avove is working fine if i run this on SourceTree terminal window.         ###SourceTree is GUI of git.

Comment: @Denis, this grep command is working fine with git log but not with git blame. Not getting whats the issue with this git blame.

Comment: @ManishMankar `git blame` does not have a `--grep` option that I know of; `git log` does. That means you have to use pipe, hence my sub-shell suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

For a pipe to work, you might try to execute the commands in a separate shell, as in "[How to make pipes work with `Runtime.exec()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316/6309)"

```
String[] cmd = {
"/bin/sh",
"-c",
"git blame StandOnLinux.java | grep e8a93e7d"
};

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Make sure the default `$PATH` does include `git`.