# How to use pipes in a java Runtime.exec

Tags: java, pipe, runtime.exec

I'm getting null as the output of this command line.

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/find",baseDir+"/..","-type","f","|","/usr/bin/grep",filter1,"|","/usr/bin/grep",filter2,"|","/usr/bin/wc","-l"});
result.waitFor();
BufferedReader echo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getInputStream()));
writer.print(echo.readLine());
echo.close();
```

Is it the pipes "|"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the shell commands like `|`, use `/bin/bash` as your first argument to exec, `-c` as the second, and the entire string (including `find`, it's parameters and the pipe etc) as the third.

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/find " + baseDir+"/.. -type f | /usr/bin/grep " +filter1 + "| /usr/bin/grep "+filter2+" | /usr/bin/wc -l"});
```