# Execute command with prompt YES input

Tags: java, command-line, runtime.exec

```
 public static String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      p.waitFor();
     }   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

given code is working fine to execute any command but I have a command which want YES/NO as input. How I can give the input to command for further execution?

ex.

```
executeCommand("pio app data-delete model");

output-
[INFO] [App$] Data of the following app (default channel only) will be deleted. Are you sure?
[INFO] [App$]     App Name: twittermodeling
[INFO] [App$]       App ID: 14
[INFO] [App$]  Description: None
Enter 'YES' to proceed:
```

So How I can give YES to them for further execution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example like for an input string the expected behavior?

Comment: If I get it...you want to use the value returned by `p.waitFor()` to say give a prompt `Enter 'YES' to proceed:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to pass "YES" to an unix command, you could prefix it by `echo YES |`. `echo YES | pio app data-delete model` should force deletion.

In the context of runtime.exec() thought the pipe can't be evaluated correctly, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec) for more information.

However, the first thing you should do is check if the pio command does not have a "force" flag, usually -f, which would omit user interactions.

Comment: It is working fine on terminal but when I execute this command echo YES | pio app data-delete model in java , its not worked

Comment: I think it is due to pipeline character |

Comment: let me check, there might be a way to use runtime.exec() with composed commands.

Comment: done, for your information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec), you should either put the command in a script and execute it instead, or call a shell environment and pass it the command

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
line = reader.readLine();

if (line.toLowerCase().equals("yes")){
    ....
}
else if (line.toLowerCase().equals("no")){
    ....
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to provide Yes or No as input so it can further execute the command. Command is not give YES or NO

Comment: please give us some more info in your question