# Android, launch one process which handles output of another one process

Tags: android, process

```
 proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ls"});
```

Using code above we can launch ls, we can pass arguments.
But how to launch something like this:

```
ls | egrep "init|sys"
```

**About 'Duplicate':**
Unfortunately original question solution doesn't work for me.
Exception:

```
Error running exec(). Command: [/bin/sh, -c, logcat | grep something] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec)

Comment: Unfortunately original question solution doesn't work for me.
Exception:
Error running exec(). Command: [/bin/sh, -c, logcat | grep something] Working Directory: null Environment: null