# How to get the output of a piped bash command in Java

Tags: java, linux, process, runtime.exec

I am following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) Which work fine if I do only `ps -elf`.
If I try to pipe it `ps -elf | grep php` This will return nothing.
I did make sure I have a php process running `<?php sleep('10000000');`
which is found by running `ps -elf | grep php` directly on the command line.

The code I am using (from the other post above) and that is **working** unless I use pipe:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -elf");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(line + "\n\n\n\n");

}
input.close();
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316