# How to make Pipe symbol or Grep work in an Android process runtime command?

Tags: android, linux, bash, pipe, runtime

I am trying to execute the following command;

```
String cmd = "/system/bin/netstat -"+firstString+" | grep http";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
Log.d("1:CMD VALUE", cmd);
```

The log result is `1:CMD VALUE: /system/bin/netstat -a | grep http`

However, the output is **not** getting filtered for the 'http' parameter. The regular "/system/bin/netstat -a" result is what I get for the "/system/bin/netstat -a | grep http`" command as well. Why is this? Is this because of the pipe symbol or the grep command?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: if `grep` is a binary executable file (a program), then it simply may be absent in Android system since Android is not full linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316/1904517

Comment: @iagreen: I tried the String array before I posted the question, but still, it gives the same output, i.e. grep doesn't work or the pipe doesn't work?! . My cmd array was {"/system/bin/netstat", "-"+firstString, " | grep http"} - does this look correct? Vlad: How to check if it is absent?

Comment: No.  The important part about that link is that "|" is not supported by `exec`, but by the shell.  You need to invoke `sh` and then have `sh` run your command.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I added "bash -c" to my command, and I get the message that I need root permission to invoke bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers on this website were not very clear. Here is the solution. 
You need to append `"/system/bin/sh -c"` before your runtime command for grep to work. 
Cheers.